# Andriod studio can't recognise my device as android device

Tags: android, adb

I was using my android device for app testing, but suddenly  I can't run it now.

i tried `troubleshoot device connections`, so i get this after `rescan devices`:

> Android Studio detected 7 device(s).
>   Found 7 USB device(s) not recognized as Android devices:

```
A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Device 
Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD Camera 
Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. RNE-L21 
Intel Corp. 
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Nordic Semiconductor ASA Wireless Receiver
```

so, my device is `Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. RNE-L21`, how can I recognize it as android?

Comment: Can you show us, what's the output of `adb devices`?

Comment: no devices found

Comment: Which operating system are you using? On Linux you sometimes have to mess around with udev rules to get it to work

Comment: I am wondering, did you make sure that "developer mode" on your phone has been activated?

Comment: using `ubuntu 20.04` and developer mode is active on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have checked **Developer options** inside settings.